# postfix getting localhost IP address

Tags: postfix

HI i am able to send and received mail but getting the IP address of my Localhost. I have changed same to my 192.168.153.138 but still gettig same

```
Feb 24 08:43:39 mail postfix/virtual[11795]: 70655E0E01: to=<root@rishirich.org>, relay=virtual, delay=129, delays=59/43/0/26, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Feb 24 08:43:40 mail postfix/smtp[11683]: 60A04E374D: to=<gaurav@rishirich.org>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=250, delays=2.2/0.12/2.3/245, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA([127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 70655E0E01)
Feb 24 08:43:41 mail postfix/qmgr[11324]: 70655E0E01: removed
```

**root@mail:/etc/postfix# postconf -n**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
debug_peer_level = 4
debug_peer_list =
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = 192.168.153.138, 123.236.33.216
myhostname = mail.rishirich.org
mynetworks = 192.168.153.138
myorigin = /etc/mailname
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps $transport_maps
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sender_canonical_maps =
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/sdd_transport_maps.regexp
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name powered by Easy Hosting Control Panel (ehcp) on Ubuntu, www.ehcp.net
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,check_client_access hash:/var/lib/pop-before-smtp/hosts,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/access
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 4
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_limit_message="The user you are trying to reach is over quota."
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_override=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_overquota_bounce=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: reject_unauth_destination=hash:/etc/postfix/access
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_mailbox_extended=yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that **relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024** is the configured setting for your content filter. This is probably how you are restricting spam.

Comment: That particular configuration setting can be found in `master.cf`. `postconf` output only covers settings that go into `main.cf` (or are specified vi `-o`).